# Unable to install the package "png" on R, possible conflict with Anaconda?

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I'm trying to install the package "png" on RStudio but I get the following error, I run on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file,
     DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

     unable to load shared object '/home/doma/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
     library/3.4/png/libs/png.so':

     libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

     Error: loading failed
     Execution halted
```

I have installed Anaconda so I was wondering if it could be the problem, since the file libpng16.so.16 is actually installed in anaconda's libraries.
Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't, the R package calls the library from its own directory.  Try to reinstall, use `remove.packages()` to remove the package.

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 4):

You must install this ubuntu package before installing png in R.
Try the following:

Installing directly using apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install libpng16-16
```

If this doesn't work, please install manually.

```
wget https://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.34/libpng-1.6.34.tar.xz
tar xf libpng-1.6.34.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.6.34/
./configure
sudo make check
sudo make install
```

Finally, install R package in R terminal.

```
> install.packages('png')
```

Comment: First, I had to update my environment variable (`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`) before starting R. Then I could run `install.packages("png")`

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS7, system-wide libpng is 15, while anaconda has 16. During `install.packages('png')`, called is `gcc` with flag `-L/<path_to_anaconda>/anaconda/lib`. I temporarily removed anaconda path from PATH variable, then the `gcc` command of `install.packages('png')` becomes without the flag, and `install.packages('png')` installed successfully.